# C#: Multiplying two numbers in a datagridview cell does not return a precise result

Tags: c#, winforms

In an app I'm working on `Winforms`, I'm trying to multiply two cells in a datagridview and get the total value (quantity * price = total)
The problem is that the result is not precise

**Example:**
[image]

Like you can see on screenshot price is `3.469,99` but when I multiply by one `1` get `3.470,00`. This need to be `3.469,99`

**Here is my code:**

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
            {
    
                if (int.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value?.ToString(), out int qty))
                {
                    var price = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value;
                    var total = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3];
     
                    decimal result = qty * (decimal) price; // <--- HERE 
    
                    total.Value = result;
                }
            }
    
        }

}
```

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: What version of .NET is this using?

Comment: What type has price? Is it actually a decimal and do we see all decimal places and not just something "formatted" in the grid.

Comment: Price column has set in `Cell Style`  as `Numeric` with format `N2` with 2 decimal places.

Comment: Am using .Net  4.7.2

Comment: Thats not the type thats grid formatting . Could you just debug the code and tell us what type price it is and while you at it the content of that variable?

Comment: @Ralf check my new update! I upload screenshot of debug

Comment: Does the content of result looks right? If so i would look up if the type of the Total column is correct like @Loathing suggests in his answer.

Comment: @Ralf the result is `3.470,00` that is not correct. I will check now

Comment: If you bind a `DataTable`, then you don't need to do this. Add [Expression Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-7.0).

Comment: Seems unbound grid. If so, set the [ValueType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.valuetype?view=netframework-4.8&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn.ValueType)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) property of the _price_ and _total_ columns to `typeof(decimal)`. Otherwise, `3469.99` input by code is considered as a value of type _double_. You should use type _decimal_ for the monetary values.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the DataType of the "Total" column is `int`, but should be `decimal`.

For example, this creates the same behavior as the screenshot:

```
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(int)); // <- this should be decimal
dgv.DataSource = table;
Form ff = new Form();
ff.Controls.Add(dgv);
ff.Load += delegate {
    dgv.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "n2";
    int qty = 1;
    double price = 3469.99;
    decimal result = qty * (decimal) price;
    table.Rows.Add(new Object[] { result });
};
Application.Run(ff);
```

Another possibility is your price is 3469.994999999995.

This results in 3469.99 for the price, and 3470.00 for the total.

E.g:

```
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(double));
table.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(decimal));
dgv.DataSource = table;
Form ff = new Form();
ff.Controls.Add(dgv);
ff.Load += delegate {
    dgv.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "n2";
    dgv.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "n2";
    int qty = 1;
    double price = 3469.994999999995;
    decimal result = qty * (decimal) price;
    table.Rows.Add(new Object[] { price, result });
};
Application.Run(ff);
```

Comment: i try to set `qty` to int, `price` to double, `result` to decimal and when debug the types is correct but `total` again the some problem. Not `3469.994999999995` its `3470`